# Using Irvine32 DumpRegs causes antivirus to stop my program from running?

Tags: windows, assembly, masm, antivirus, irvine32

I am taking Assembly this semester.  I am trying to use DumpRegs to display my registers, however, I get an error when running without debugging. The program builds (successfully it says), hangs and then my cmd prompt displays: "The system cannot execute the specified program."

If I debug, Visual Studio says "Insufficient resources exist to complete the requested service", then my antivirus attempts to quarantine "Generic RX BM-OC!257C1442E357 " at the time of running.  I just ran a scan and I have no viruses, only downloads have been the Irvine library off of his site earlier today.  Any ideas?  I'm on a 64 bit machine, but their site said it was tested for 32 bit and 64 bit machines.

Here is the incredibly simple code:

```
include Irvine32.inc


.code
main PROC

    mov eax,5
    add  eax,6

    call DumpRegs


    exit

main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: What antivirus software are you using?  Presumably it has a false-positive on Irvine32 code, and is stopping your program from running, so process startup fails.  There's no error code for "stopped by virus scanner", so the process-creation system call (made by the debugger) actually returns something else.  BTW, do any of the error messages literally say "insufficient memory" like in your question title?  The error you quote in the question body is "Insufficient resources ...".

Comment: Hi Peter, when I attempt to debug in VS, it says resources. I'm assuming something was happening with the memory somewhere along the way.  Was that an incorrect use of the term?  I just associate resources with memory.  Oh, and McAfee antivirus.

Comment: It was the antivirus.  I was weary to make any changes with the error responses.  Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: The resource in question could equally be process-ID numbers, or some other OS-imposed limit.  The failure code the debugger gets doesn't tell it which resource was exhausted.  (And like I said, in this case it's not really any resource exhaustion, it's probably the antivirus using that error code).  The important point is that **quoting error messages exactly** is what makes it possible for other people to find them when searching.  *that's* why I was making a big deal about it.